# TestNG results groups on Jenkins

Tags: testing, selenium, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I have a tests suites as below

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="SailPoint IIQ Suite" preserver-order=true>
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="Test1.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="Test2.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="Test3.xml"></suite-file>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

So , I want Jenkins should show, test results tables based on Suites Names but it shows tables based on Java package names as [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML Plugins and print html output to see results as per your requirement.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin